# Making a jQuery Tab Selected based on errors present

Tags: jquery, error-handling, jquery-ui-tabs

I am working to get a tab in my web application to show selected IF there is an error within it, because I have a form that spans the two tabs. For now if there is an error the user can not see the error message inside tabs-2 and they don't know what to fix. I have the following code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a id="Tab-1" href="#tabs-1">Tabs 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="Tab-2" href="#tabs-2" ">Tabs 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div style="display:block;" id="tabs-1" class="tab-content" name="content">
    <span>Content here</span>
  </div>
  <div style="display:block;" id="tabs-2" class="tab-content" name="content">
    <span id="ETError" class="error-template"></span>
    <span class="error-message">Must enter at least one more</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
  var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

  $j(function() {
    $j( '#tabs' ).tabs();
    $j('#tabs > div').each(function(i) {
      if($j(this).find('#ETError.error-message').length < 0)
        $j('#tabs').tabs('select', i);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What's the logic to find if there's a error or not?

Comment: @PalashMondal with this application the page will refresh when submitted and right now the error isn't seen so the user doesn't know why they can not proceed because the error message next to the form field is inside tabs-2

Comment: Have you tried this `$j(this).find('.error-message').length > 0` instead of `$j(this).find('#ETError.error-message').length < 0`?

Comment: @PalashMondal yea I tried that as well as `$j(this).find('#ETError').length < 0` not sure what I'm missing here

Comment: Have you tried with `length > 0` or `length < 0` ? Since, if there's a error message means length will be > 0...

Comment: @PalashMondal hmmm, that I just tried and that isn't working either

Comment: @urbanrunic check out my answer below. Just removed unwanted code and added little explaination too. And see demo as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to set tab to active if there's an error message is present. Check this if that's what you wanted or let me know if there's something else I'm missing here.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
var $tabs = $j( '#tabs' ).tabs();       

$j("button").click(function(){
    var $errorSpan = $j("span").filter(function(index){        
        if($j(this).hasClass("error-message"))
        return $j(this);
    });

    var errorTabIndex = $j(".tab-content").index($errorSpan.closest(".tab-content"));

    console.log(errorTabIndex);

    // for jQuery < 1.10
    $tabs.tabs({
        selected: errorTabIndex
    });

    //for jQuery >= 1.10
    $tabs.tabs( "option", "active", errorTabIndex);

});
```

I've added handler to check for `error-div` on button tap. You might want to set it to form submit or something.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/gEzpc/2/)

**Update**

What is done is, a filter is applied on `span.error-message`. If found any it returns that span. Then we can find the tab which is having that error message and set it active.

Comment: This is great! Thank you. I also found this article http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-select-method showing that the select is deprecated

Comment: @urbanrunic yeah.. thanks for informing I didn't know that. I'll update answer soon with both methods for future visitors.